Your library compilation option specifies that the compiler external helper (tslib) is needed but it is not installed
After i clone a project to my machine, I did pnpm install then use pnpm running my backend project it with this error:
enter image description here
tslib is installed
my node version is 18.19.1
This is in my package.json : "tslib": "^2.3.0"
Does anyone know what is the reason cause this issue?
Tred use the workspace TypeScript version as it is different to VS code's version
I originally use node v20, then tried downgrade to v18.19.1 which all my colleagues are use, still not working.
Uninstall pnpm(first time, using Homebrew to install it), second time use npm installed it, same issue.
